# Помогите с регуляркой в PHP

Tags: php

В корне сайта есть каталог `./temp/с` лог файлами по заявкам.

Есть такой код:

```
$scandir = scandir('./temp/', TRUE);
```

Который получает список заявок:

```
[0] => 23339_19-09-2017_14:34:15_post.log
[1] => 23339_19-09-2017_14:34:15_charge.log
[2] => 23316_15-09-2017_03:37:20_2co.log
[3] => 23316_15-09-2017_03:37:10_post.log
[4] => 23316_15-09-2017_03:37:10_charge.log
```

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая будет находить имя файла по `id` заказа.
Например: Хочу получить имя файла по `id = 23316`, функция должна выдать имя файла `23316_15-09-2017_03:37:10_post.log`

Comment: у вас один ид идет у 3 путей, вы хотите выбирать только 1 файл указанного ид? Или вы хотите по строке искать файлы? Не совсем понятно, о чем идет речь.

Comment: Мне нужно получить любой файл, который начинается с 23316 и заканчивается "post.log"

Comment: `/^23316.+_post\.log$/i`

Comment: `/(?=23316).+(?>post\.log)/i`

Answer (score 3):

А функция [glob()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php) интереснее (примеры на моих данных):

```
$id = '59';
$delimiter = '-';
$tail = '.7z';
$arr = glob("{$id}{$delimiter}*{$tail}", GLOB_NOSORT);
var_dump($arr);
```

Результат

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "59-0020.7z"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "59-0021.7z"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "59-0022.7z"
}
```

---

```
$folder = '../bin/php/php-7.2.0RC4-Win32-VC15-x86/';
$id = 'lib';
$delimiter = '';
$tail = '.dll';
$arr = glob("{$folder}{$id}{$delimiter}*{$tail}");
var_dump($arr);
```

Результат

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(56) "../bin/php/php-7.2.0RC4-Win32-VC15-x86/libcrypto-1_1.dll"
  [1]=>
  string(53) "../bin/php/php-7.2.0RC4-Win32-VC15-x86/libenchant.dll"
  [2]=>
  string(48) "../bin/php/php-7.2.0RC4-Win32-VC15-x86/libpq.dll"
  [3]=>
  string(50) "../bin/php/php-7.2.0RC4-Win32-VC15-x86/libsasl.dll"
  [4]=>
  string(52) "../bin/php/php-7.2.0RC4-Win32-VC15-x86/libsodium.dll"
  [5]=>
  string(50) "../bin/php/php-7.2.0RC4-Win32-VC15-x86/libssh2.dll"
  [6]=>
  string(53) "../bin/php/php-7.2.0RC4-Win32-VC15-x86/libssl-1_1.dll"
}
```

Comment: Нужно получить любой файл, который начинается с 23316 и заканчивается "post.log"

Comment: @And, так в чем проблема? Получаем данные от glob() и берем элемент `[0]`. Можно даже сразу так `glob()[0]` :P

Comment: @And, или вы не может подставить переменные $folder, $id, $delimiter, $tail как '../temp/', '23316', '-', '_post.log'?

Comment: кто минусит то, неплохой вариант же

Comment: @teran лично я плюсую ваш вариант, т.к. тоже считаю glob() хорошей альтернативой ) UDP: вариант не ваш, а с glob() :) Извиняюсь, что сбил вас с толку )

Comment: @Эдуард мой вариант не с  `glob` :)

Comment: @Visman, возможно и так, сразу не подумал об этом, только для этой цели, лучше выключить сортировку `GLOB_NOSORT`, чтобы работало быстро.

Answer (score 2):

Этот вариант найдет все файлы, начинающиеся с `23316` и заканчивающиеся на `post.log`

```
$need = '23316';

$array = [
    '23339_19-09-2017_14:34:15_post.log',
    '23316_15-09-2017_03:37:20_2co.log',
    '23339_19-09-2017_14:34:15_charge.log',
    '23316_15-09-2017_03:37:10_post.log'
];

echo '<pre>', print_r(need_file($array, $need), 1), '</pre>';


function need_file($arr, $need) {
    return array_filter($arr, function($item) use($need) {
        return preg_match('~^'. $need .'.+_post.log$~', $item);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$files = [
    0 => '23339_19-09-2017_14:34:15_post.log',
    1 => '23339_19-09-2017_14:34:15_charge.log',
    2 => '23316_15-09-2017_03:37:20_2co.log',
    3 => '23316_15-09-2017_03:37:10_post.log',
    4 => '23316_15-09-2017_03:37:10_charge.log'
];
```

> Мне нужно написать функцию, которая будет находить имя файла по `id`
>   заказа.

```
function findLogById($id){
    global $files;

    foreach($files as $f){
        if(preg_match("/^$id.+_post.log$/i", $f)){
            return $f;
         }
    }

    throw new Exception("no log file for ID#$id");
}
```

выведет первый подходящий файл.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант подходит)